# how to call a class during eclipse plugin installation?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, installation

During the install of my plugin in Eclipse, I'd like to call a method to perform some validations.  I tried [this approach](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/how-to-add-custom-install-actions-to-your-next-eclipse-ide-plug-in/), but the class isn´t being called.

Have anyone already tried something like this?
Any help is welcome.

Comment: Another place to ask would be the eclipse.p2 forum on the [Eclipse Forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums)